# Show headers and body text of an HTTP request in Ruby

Tags: ruby, request

I'm sure this is easy, but I've searched pretty extensively and been unable to find an answer. I'm using the `Net::Http` library in Ruby and am trying to figure out how I show the complete body of an HTTP GET request? Something like the following:

```
GET /really_long_path/index.html?q=foo&s=bar HTTP\1.1
Cookie: some_cookie;
Host: remote_host.example.com
```

I am looking for the raw **REQUEST** , not the **RESPONSE** to be captured.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The #to_hash method of a request object may be useful. Here's an example to build a GET request and inspect headers:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI('http://example.com/cached_response')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

req['X-Crazy-Header'] = "This is crazy"

puts req.to_hash # hash of request headers
# => {"accept"=>["*/*"], "user-agent"=>["Ruby"], "x-crazy-header"=>["This is crazy"]}
```

And an example for a POST request to set form data and inspect headers and body:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI('http://www.example.com/todo.cgi')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)

req.set_form_data('from' => '2005-01-01', 'to' => '2005-03-31')

puts req.to_hash # hash of request headers
# => {"accept"=>["*/*"], "user-agent"=>["Ruby"], "content-type"=>["application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]}

puts req.body # string of request body
# => from=2005-01-01&to=2005-03-31
```

Comment: While not exactly what I was expecting, this is as close to what I need as I believe is currently possible. Thank you!

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for but it point me in the right direction, thx 

Answer (score 2):

Net::HTTP has a method called [set_debug_output](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html#M000665)...  It will print the information you're looking for.

```
http = Net::HTTP.new
http.set_debug_output $stderr
http.start { .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the request headers, not the request body.

To access that you can take a look at the documentation for Net::HTTPHeader (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPHeader.html). This module is included in Net::HTTPRequest objects can can be accessed directly.

Comment: Yes. I meant headers. Is there a way to print everything at once?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do something more complex with the response from the request (`GET` call) this example shows how to perform `GET` and reading headers from the response:

```
  access_token = API::TokenManager.valid_token
  config = Rails.configuration.my_web_app["api"]
  uri = URI("#{config.fetch("base_url")}/api_endpoint?access_token=#{access_token}")
  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
  puts response.to_hash["x-app-usage"]["call_count"]
```

=>
`{"call_count":48,"total_cputime":0,"total_time":80}`

Where the response is something like this (notice the headers of the response):

```
{"etag"=>["\"123\""], "x-app-usage"=>["{\"call_count\":48,\"total_cputime\":0,\"total_time\":80}"], "content-type"=>["application/json; charset=UTF-8"], "api-version"=>["v3.3"], "strict-transport-security"=>["max-age=15552000; preload"], "pragma"=>["no-cache"], "x-api-rev"=>["1002669385"], "access-control-allow-origin"=>["*"], "cache-control"=>["private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"], "x-api-trace-id"=>["AD5Ou+tTNzs"], "x-api-request-id"=>["xxx"], "expires"=>["Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"], "x-api-debug"=>["xxxxxxx=="], "date"=>["Wed, 16 Sep 2020 00:11:13 GMT"], "alt-svc"=>["h3-29=\":443\"; ma=3600,h3-27=\":443\"; ma=3600"], "connection"=>["keep-alive"], "content-length"=>["53"]}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the most basic Net::HTTP example:

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://google.com/")

# Will print response.body
Net::HTTP.get_print(uri)

# OR
# Get the response
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
puts response.body
```

You can find these and other good examples on the [Net:HTTP cheat sheet](https://github.com/augustl/net-http-cheat-sheet).

Comment: I'm not looking for the response body. I know how to get that.

Comment: So you must concerned about a POST requests (not GET requests), correct? According to Roy Fielding at least, [the body of a GET has no semantic meaning](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/9962)

Comment: I meant headers for a GET request and headers/body for the POST, I edited the original to try to clarify.