# Ruby Net::Http Api , Sending Multiple Parameters with GET/POST

Tags: ruby, request

I try to create a generic method to send GET/POST data with parameters using Ruby using NET:HTTP api ( https://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTP). Therefore, the number of parameters is not fixed. I know how to add a form data, as it is explained at : [Get HTTP request in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847956/get-http-request-in-ruby), I use;

```
uri = URI('http://www.example.com/todo.cgi') 
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req.set_form_data('from' => '2005-01-01', 'to' => '2005-03-31')
```

However it works when I know how many parameters I will have. I tried this but could not find how to add data instead of replacing.

```
parameter_list.each_with_index do |param,index|
req.set_form_data(param.to_s => value_list[index])
end
```

How can I make "For each parameter in my parameter list, add form data"?

Comment: I think it depends how you define your `parameter_list`. Whatever it is, seems like every value parameter needs a key. Sebastian's example below is one way to join key/value pairs

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own hash by joining `parameter_list` with `value_list` and converting it to hash, and then pass it as the form data, like:

```
parameter_list = %w[from to foo]
value_list = %w[2005-01-01 2005-03-31 bar]

form_data = parameter_list.zip(value_list).to_h

p form_data
# {"from"=>"2005-01-01", "to"=>"2005-03-31", "foo"=>"bar"}
req.set_form_data form_data
```

Note a constraint is both arrays must have the same size.